# Fast .gz Log File Parsing in Python

Tags: python

I have multiple log files that contain 10000+ lines of info and are Gzipped. I need a way to quickly parse each log file for relevant information and then display stats based on the information contained in all the log files. I currently use `gzip.open()` to recursively open each .gz file and then run the contents through a primitive parser.

```
def parse(logfile):
    for line in logfile:
        if "REPORT" in line:
            info = line.split()
            username = info[2]
            area = info[4]
            # Put info into dicts/lists etc.
        elif "ERROR" in line:
            info = line.split()
            ...

def main(args):
    argdir = args[1]
    for currdir, subdirs, files in os.walk(argdir):
        for filename in files:
            with gzip.open(os.path.join(currdir, filename), "rt") as log:
                parse(log)
    # Create a report at the end: createreport()
```

Is there any way to optimize this process for each file? It currently takes ~28 seconds per file on my computer to go through each .gz and every little optimization counts. I've tried using pypy and for some reason it takes 2 times longer to process a file.